# Android socket only sends when closed

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have this little app for android where I connect to my server using sockets. But when I try to send Strings from the Client to the Server it does only send the Strings, when I close the socket after I wrote PrintWriter.println("message") and PrintWriter.flush()...

```
pw.println("user$" + user.getUserName() + "/" + user.getEmail() + "/" + user.getPassword());
pw.flush();
sock.close();  //Without this it doesn't work!
```

Server-side I have this code:

```
String message;
while((message = br.readLine()) != null) { 
System.out.println("Message:" +  message);
}
```

I have tried everything, I added '\n' to the message, I used a BufferedWrite and so on, but nothing worked...

EDIT: I don't have to close the Socket entirely, I can just call sock.shutdownOutput()... But this is of course also a problem...

EDIT 2: I'm using a Nexus 7, a real device if that helps.

Okay, this seems to be a general Problem... I've made a really easy example (not android), but it still does not work. It just works if I use localhost, but as soon as I use my IP Address, I have to close the OutputStream in order to send the message... Any ideas?

Comment: How many bytes (estimation) do you send before you close the socket?

Comment: Regardless what the answer is, you should definitely close the socket anyway.

Comment: Close it once you are done, have you read up on how to use java sockets? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

Comment: Try adding sock.flush() before sock.close().

Comment: A `flush` on the highest level `Writer` / `OutputStream` should in theory be all that is needed. You could check with e.g. [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) if there are any packets sent or if the message is kept in some buffer that waits for more data.

Comment: @isnot2bad I just send one string (for testing)

sqrfv, I have to have it open until the client ends the application because I am always in communication with the server

zapl, I also thought that I'd only need a flush, but it jsut doesn't work...

Comment: try looking at an android socket project that will provide good practical example : https://github.com/koush/android-websockets

Comment: Your server reads full lines only. But the client does not terminate the line. Have you already tried to insert writer.newLine(); between writer.write("hello"); and writer.flush()?

Answer (score 2):

Your server reads full lines (`reader.readLine()`) which must be terminated by either '`\r`', '`\n`' or both ("`\r\n`"). But your client never writes any of these line termination characters (`writer.write("Hello")` only writes the characters `Hello` and nothing more).

So when you close the socket on the client, the socket-`InputStream` on the server is closed too and causes the `readLine()` call to return all the character data as one single line. (The next call to `readLine()` will then return `null`, as the stream is already closed).

(I think this is exactly what @EJP meant in his/her answer!)

Solution: Either call `writer.newLine()` whenever a line is complete, or wrap it into a `PrintWriter` instead of a `BufferedWriter`. Then you can use one of the many `println(...)` methods.

Comment: Neither writer.newLine(), nor writer.append("\n") or "\r" worked... (In my sample project)

Answer (score 0):

If you've called println() and flush(), readline() will return a line. However your *loop* won't exit until you close the socket, because that's the only thing that causes readLine() to return a null.

Comment: Yeah, but I print the message in the loop. So if the loop exits(because i close the Socket), it shouldn't print anything...

Comment: Your loop should print everything you've sent as it iterates, and then exit when you close the socket. It's not clear from your description what's actually happening.

Comment: It does not print out anything until the socket is closed...Really strange!